# SQL Query for Finding All Records Without a Certain Value

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns, albumID and photoID.

How would I return a column of all the photoID's that are not in an albumID?

For example, say I have this table and I want to find all the photoID's that are not in album 0.

```
|albumID|photoID|  
|0      |0      |  
|0      |1      |  
|1      |0      |  
|1      |2      |  
|1      |3      |
```

Then, I would only want to display photos 2 and 3.
Right now, I only have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT photoID FROM PhotoInAlbum WHERE AlbumID <> 1
```

which returns photos 0,2,3, but 0 appears in album 0.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the condition `WHERE AlbumID <> 1` only. Any specific reason? Also it wont matter much in this scenario, but tag your database.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT photoID FROM PhotoInAlbum WHERE photoID NOT IN
(
SELECT photoID from PhotoInAlbum WHERE AlbumID = 0
)
```

Use a `subquery`

Comment: `NOT IN` has a bit surprising behavior when NULL's are involved, so I usually recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: On the other hand the non-correlated `NOT IN` is usually more readable than `NOT EXISTS` and situations where the subquery can return nulls is extremely rare. But yes, it is a point to consider. For the given problem `NOT IN` is a good approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also approach this using a self left-join.  It would seem to make sense to also return the albums to which each photo belongs.  If you really just want photo IDs, then you can replace my select with `SELECT DISTINCT p1.photoID` instead.

```
SELECT p1.albumID, p1.photoID, p2.photoID
FROM PhotoInAlbum p1
LEFT JOIN PhotoInAlbum p2
    ON p1.photoID = p2.photoID AND p2.albumID = 0
WHERE p2.photoID IS NULL;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a photo can occur multiple times in the table, but you want to get a list of photos (those that don't exist in album 0) and you probably don't want a photo listed more than once. So aggregate your rows with `GROUP BY` in order to get one row per photo. Use `HAVING` to limit your results so to keep only those that are not in album 0.

```
select photoID
from PhotoInAlbum 
group by photoID
having count(case when albumID = 0 then 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT photoID FROM PhotoInAlbum WHERE photoID NOT IN (SELECT albumID FROM PhotoInAlbum)
```